# Retrieving city information from a city table based on user ID in a post table

Tags: reactjs, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables in my database: city and post. The city table contains information about cities, including the city name and ID, while the post table contains information about posts, including the user ID of the person who published the post.

I am trying to retrieve the city name for each post in the post table, based on the user ID associated with that post. Specifically, I want to query the city table and retrieve the city name associated with the user ID in the post table in json response
thank you for your help i have searched for this problem and i can't find any solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [`hasOneThrough` relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) in the Post model for the City model like:

```php
// Post model
class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            City::class,
            User::class,
            'city_id', // foreign key on the users table
            'id', // local key on the cities table
            'user_id', // local key on the posts table
            'id' // foreign key on the users table
        );
    }
}
```

The key part is defining the `city()` relationship as `hasOneThrough`.

After this in your controller, you can simply retrieve the city using the with method like:

```php
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::with('user.city')->get();

    return response()->json($posts);
}
```